# Удаление установки NetBeans IDE 7.1

Tags: ide, java, netbeans

Помогите! При попытке удаления выбивает ошибку

> Указанный целевой компонент, nb-base/7.1.0.0.0 не найден в реестре.

Если жму продолжить установку, то деинсталлятор закрывается. Если жму нет, то деинсталлятор тоже закрывается.

Answer (score 1):

1. найди на диске и удали папку
2. зайди в реестр и почисти все что связано с NetBeans
3. зайди в документы пользователя и удали временные папки NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

Ну еще и как вариант: установить NetBeans IDE 7.1 поверх еще раз, а потом попробовать удалить опять - может инсталлятор просто похерен был. Но а вообще, то вопрос не в тему - проблема деинсталляции NetBeans IDE 7.1 не отличается от деинсталляции какого-нибудь VeryBestFreePornViewer 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте установлена ли JVM, без нее установщик не сможет ни удалить, ни становить.